# Culture issues after installing windows update KB3136000

Tags: .net, wpf, culture, windows-update

after installing windows update KB3136000 the WPF application behaves unexpected when changing the CurrentThread cultures.

Executing the following code in WPF (targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var defaultCultureInfo = string.Format("Default Culture: Culture: {0}, UICulture: {1}, ThreadID: {2}",
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var culture = new CultureInfo("hu-HU");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
    var newCultureInfo = string.Format("New Culture (Should be hu-HU): Culture: {0}, UICulture: {1}, ThreadID: {2}",
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(defaultCultureInfo);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(newCultureInfo);

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

gives the following results (German is my OS language):

```
Default Culture: Culture: de-DE, UICulture: de-DE, ThreadID: 8
New Culture (Should be hu-HU): Culture: de-DE, UICulture: de-DE, ThreadID: 8
```

Executing the same code when targeting .NET Framework 4.5 gives the following (correct) results:

```
Default Culture: Culture: de-DE, UICulture: de-DE, ThreadID: 8
New Culture (Should be hu-HU): Culture: hu-HU, UICulture: hu-HU, ThreadID: 8
```

Executing similar code in Console Application when targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 gives correct results as well.

This issue seems to occur when changing the WPF application's culture to something different than the operating system's culture after installing KB3136000.

Is there anyone encountering similar issues? Is there a way to report issues to Microsoft without a Microsoft account. The procedure we tried on Connect Microsoft failed after the first step:
"You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection."

EDIT:

Starting a new thread also has strange behavior (.NET 4.6.1, WPF). Add the following code to the code above:

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Thread: Culture: {0}, UICulture: {1}, {2}", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }));
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
Console.WriteLine("After Thread-Execution: Culture: {0}, UICulture: {1}, {2}", thread.CurrentCulture, thread.CurrentUICulture, thread.ManagedThreadId);
```

Results:

```
In Thread: Culture: de-DE, UICulture: de-DE, 10
After Thread-Execution: Culture: hu-HU, UICulture: hu-HU, 10
```

Comment: Bug side: "..., we recommend that you always explicitly set the culture of your main application thread, and not rely on the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property to define the culture of the main application thread." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you had asked me what I *expected* I would have said your "bug" is my "expected behavior". Why would setting the default culture somehow change my current culture? If you want to set the thread culture, set the thread culture. Setting the default should not change an already existing culture in my point of view.

Comment: But why do the different frameworks and application types behave differently? And why does uninstalling the KB change the behavior? Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @LK11 are you sure they behave differently? I'd bet that you've changed the user's or the system locale recently. The `Default` *never* caused the trhread's culture to change

Comment: I am absolutely sure. We encounter this problem on several systems. Always after installing KB3136000. We did not change locales on any system.

Comment: We had same problems here... on some systems the default culture thread is changed automatically to default language pack. Did you found a solution for this ?